# Dell windows 10 tablet w/ removable keyboard blocked when screensaver

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, screensaver, tablet-pc

In our work enviorment we have a few Dell windows 10 laptops. they all have screensaver enabled. for some unknown reason, the removable keyboard is ignored untill a user logs in, though you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> on the keyboard to access the login screen, which is being ignored.

it is not an option to disable the screensaver.